# Using "any" and "a" along with "there is"

Tags: grammar, questions, determiners, negative-polarity-items

Could you give an explanation why *any* is not used like this:

1. Is there any car in the street?
2. Is there any book on the table?

I know that it's OK to use *a* for such sentences.

3. Is there a car in the street?
4. Is there a book on the table?

Both *any* and *a* do mean “one”, but there must be some difference between them. What is it?

Comment: With the singular *car* or *book*, your expressions seem to ask for a relative clause: *Is there any car on the street **that has a broken back window?*** *Is there any book on the table **that you would like to take home with you?***

Comment: I think it's the same reason we say *"There are no cars in the street"* and not *"There is no car in the street."*

Comment: @ScotM Would it be OK to say: Is there A car on the street that has a broken back window? If yes, what's the difference?

Answer (score 3):

I think we can't use **Any** like this because it's a determiner and a pronoun used to refer to **indefinite** or **unknown quantities** or **an unlimited entity**.

Referring to [**Any - English Grammar Today - Cambridge Dictionaries Online**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/any):

> Any as a determiner has two forms: a strong form and a weak form. The forms have different meanings.

- Weak form any: indefinite quantities
- Strong form any meaning ‘it does not matter which’

> **Warning:**
>
> We don’t use **any** with this meaning with singular countable nouns:
>
> Have you got any Italian cookery books? (or … **an** Italian cookery book?)
>
> ***Not***: Have you got any Italian cookery book?

And referring to [**Some/Any from "A guide to learning English"**](http://esl.fis.edu/grammar/rules/some.htm):

- In general, **any** is used in negative sentences and questions:

> I didn't get any nice presents for Christmas this year.
>
> I looked in the cupboard but I couldn't find any biscuits.
>
> I don't need any help.
>
> She's so rude. No wonder she doesn't have any friends.

So in that type of questions the use of **a** is more appropriate than **any** because we're dealing here with ***singular countable nouns***.

So the right statements are:

> Is there **a** car in the street?

or

> Are there **any** car**s** in the street?

Comment: Singular, countable: _do you have **any** idea how difficult this is?_

Comment: Yes I have **an** idea about how hard it is, but I just got it from [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/any) where it means that with any you have to use plural nouns as (books in the given example). And **singular** is also **countable**, that's why in mathematics counting begins from ***1***.

Comment: Ah, you left out the part that mentions the use of _any_ with singular nouns. But it is in your source :)

Comment: ***Are** there any cars in the street?*

Comment: "Is there a red car in the street?" "No." "A blue car?" "No." "A green one?" "No." "Is there *any* car in the street?" "Yes, there's a yellow one." It's grammatical and idiomatic, but only used for emphasis.

Comment: @PeterShor: Yes you're right! Imissed that. I'll Edit my answer.

Comment: Well, does it mean that "Do you have any apple?" can work? Do you have a green apple? - No. Red? - No. - Any apple? - No.

Comment: @user1425: That means that ***Do you have any apple?*** is **WRONG** but ***Do you have any apples?*** and ***Do you have an apple?*** are **CORRECT** and the same thing goes with colors green and red...

Comment: @chsdk Wait! And what about Andrew Leach's example with "any car"? He gives a context where "Is there any car in the street?" works. So, why does "any apple" not work in my context? Have you seen Andrew Leach's example?

Comment: @user1425 No referring to the *warning* in my answer wich I got from [**here**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/any) you can't use **any** with **singular countable nouns** we use the **a/an** pronoun instead or with **any** we use **plural** nouns.

Comment: @Andrew Leach I wish Andrew would clarify his stance on your warning. He is a native, after all, and I think his "car example" is likely to be idiomatic.

Comment: @user1425 A native speaker (from the UK) told me that AndrewLeach’s example sentence with any car wasn’t grammatically fine (I guess that’s just because the “any” there is a “weak form” with the singular countable noun). In lieu, he tabled an correct example with the grammatical usage with “any” of a singular countable case. Like, according to him, if someone was thinking about buying a car, you could say "is there any car you had in mind?" or something (I guess this is a “strong form” of any). Hope this elaborates on the discussion towards the right direction, and Andrew Leach will give us th

Answer (score 1):

> Could you give an explanation why ANY is not used like this:
>
> 1. Is there any car in the street? 2) Is there any book on the table?

No explanation is required at all because "ANY" is used exactly like that.

A: "Pass me my dictionary; it's on the table."

B: "There's no dictionary on the table."

A: "There has to be! I put it there."

B: "There's no dictionary."

A: "Damn! Is there **any** book on the table?"

B: "Yes, there is a copy of "Little Women".